# Is there a list of linux ddcutil-supported (or similar) monitors?

Tags: monitors

I have older monitor and switching input is action for 5s or so. I could really benefit from fast switching and being able to set other stuff like pip/etc.

The problem is, that monitor manufacturers notoriously to ignore linux, despite of recent gaming on linux on rise or lot of guys working on linux.

It's not a problem to buy a monitor, test it and return it, but ideally I'd like to go for know-to-be-supported devices.

What I want: flat, 27-30", 16:9 2560x1440 or 16:10 (not a 4K), matte, ips. Controllable from linux cli, fast switching between sources, ideally pip/pbp, ideally kvm. Ideally NOT gigabyte (I tested $600 4k one and was 'impressed' by build and namely sw quality)

Is there some monitor known to support dccutil or similar? OR known monitor brand, which documents its API so that we can code cli/GUI app?

Comment: Basically any monitor with DDC/CI should work in terms of controlling input switching; however, PIP/PBP is not really part of the DDC spec, and therefore is only currently implemented via proprietary commands. Many Dell monitors [seem to support *some* degree of control over DDC](https://github.com/rockowitz/ddcutil/labels/PBP), as do some Philips monitors apparently, but nothing is going to be "known-supported" for PIP/PBP.

Comment: @JMY1000 thanks. ddc/ci to some extent and proprietary commands has some non-negligible chance of bricking hw. Let me extend the question: do we know manufacturer, who shares its api? So far I tested only gigabyte to find out, that their own coding sucks big time, so this is not the brand.

Comment: AFAIK, no. The best option you probably have would be packet-sniffing one of the official apps offered by the vendor.